# UITabBarView With UINavigation

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `tabBar` view with 3 `view controllers`:

`viewController` number 3 is `rootView` of `navigationController` then from this `view` I have `button` to `subView` and when I press `back bar button` I return to the `rootView` but without the `tabBar` control
So how should I return from the `subView` to the `rootView` with the `tabBarView` ?
thanks for helpers :)

Comment: You must explain better what you are doing and what is the problem to get a good help. Also show your code, where you met the issue.

Comment: are you using _storyboard_ ? How are you presenting the `subView` ? Show the `code` of adding the `viewControllers` to `tabBar`.

Comment: yes I'm using storyboard. i connected the tab bar directly to nav control